# How do I go about implementing CursorLoader without using a Listview?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-cursorloader

after going through loads of tutorials on `CursorLoader` for using with a `SQLiteDatabase`, I'm still a bit confused. Being a beginner, I was unaware of the advantages of `Listview` and instead chose to use several `ViewGroups` in a vertical order in my first app.

Now that my app is complete and I want to optimize it by using a `CursorLoader` for doing all the SQL operations (CRUD), I don't have any idea how to implement it.

Is it possible to extract the information from the returned adapter and update the TextViews inside the ViewGroups?

Furthermore, I'm using a DatabaseHelper for all my SQL requirements. Do I need to re-write it to use a Loader? How tough would it be?

Sorry if this is a naive question, but the official documentation are not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to extract the information from the returned adapter

There is no "returned adapter". `CursorLoader` is a `Loader` that returns a `Cursor`. None of those things are "adapters" as the term is used in Android.

> and update the TextViews inside the ViewGroups?

Yes. The `Cursor` API allows you to set which row you want to work with (`moveToPosition()`, etc.), from which you can retrieve columns (`getString()`, etc.).

> Do I need to re-write it to use a Loader?

`CursorLoader` works only with a  `ContentProvider`. If your `DatabaseHelper` (presumably a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`) is used by a `ContentProvider`, then your `CursorLoader` can work with that `ContentProvider`. Other alternatives include:

- not bothering with the `Loader` framework, and just using `AsyncTask` and kin for doing your database I/O in the background
- using [my `SQLiteCursorLoader`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex), which works directly with a `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: Wow, looks like your `SQLiteCursorLoader` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for your quick answer.